# ¿como agregar n posisiones a un array mediante un boton laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-8

```
   public function add_compra($id_compras)
   {
```

**Hola, primero rescato el id de la tabla productos**

```
   $producto=Productos::where('id_productos','=',$id_compras)->get();
```

**luego obtengo todos los datos de dicho id y la coloco en una variable producto_compra**

```
 $producto_compra = Productos::join('talla', 'productos.id_talla', '=', 'talla.id_talla')
 ->join('talla_ropa', 'productos.id_talla_ropa', '=', 'talla_ropa.id_talla_ropa')
 ->join('categorias', 'productos.id_categoria', '=', 'categorias.id_categoria')-
```

> select('talla.id_talla','talla_ropa.id_talla_ropa','productos.id_productos','productos.nombre','p
> roductos.codigo','productos.cantidad_disponible','talla.talla','talla_ropa.talla_ropa')
> ->where('productos.id_productos','=',$id_compras)
> ->get();
> **luego almaceno la sesion en una variable**

```
    $cont_prod_compra=session()->get('cont_prod_compra',0); 
    $producto_array_sesion[$cont_prod_compra]=session()->get('productos_add_compra');
```

**creo el array**

```
  $producto_array[$cont_prod_compra] = array( 
 'id_producto_compra'=>$producto_compra[0]->id_productos,
   'codigo_producto_compra'=>$producto_compra[0]->codigo,
   'nombre_producto_compra'=>$producto_compra[0]->nombre,
   'id_talla_compra'=>$producto_compra[0]->id_talla,
  'id_talla_ropa_compra'=>$producto_compra[0]->id_talla_ropa,
  'talla_compra'=>$producto_compra[0]->talla,
 'talla_ropa_compra'=>$producto_compra[0]->talla_ropa,
 'cantidad_disponible_compra'=>$producto_compra[0]->cantidad_disponible,


  );
```

**esa varible anterior la almaceno en la sesion**

```
  $producto_array_sesion=$producto_array;
```

**pregunto si no existe esa sesion, luego me añade en la sesion**

```
    if(!isset($producto_array_sesion)){ 
    $cont_prod_compra++;
    session()->put('productos_add_compra',$productos_add_compra);
    session()->put('cont_prod_compra',$cont_prod_compra);
    }
```

**muestro por pantalla el elemento a añadir**

```
 if(isset($producto_array_sesion)){
  foreach($producto_array_sesion as $indice=>$arreglo){
  echo"Producto :".$indice;
  foreach($arreglo  as $key=>$value){
   echo $key ." : ".$value;

  }

 }

  } 


return view('compras.verCarrito',compact('producto_array_sesion'));

}
```

**ahora bien solo me añade un elemento en la posicion 0 (la que corresponde), luego al apretar
nuevamente el boton pues este se setea y me añade nuevamente en la posicion 0 el nuevo elemento**

Hola, creo que yo me equivoque en formular la pregunta  lo que necesito es que ese elemento pase como coleccion a mi variable sesion    que quede  mas o menos asi

```
 0->elemento pera
 1->elemento manzana
 2->elemento durazno
```

al dar click al boton 3 veces
asi debe ir creciendo de uno en uno

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es solo un ejemplo si se fijan esa coleccion tiene  no solo la pocicion 0

tiene la 1 la 2 la 3 etc

eso quiero llegar

en el blade recorro asi la coleccion (lo cual esta mal porque me lanza error)
foreach() argument must be of type array|object, int given

```
    @foreach($producto_array_sesion as $ingreso)

  @foreach($ingreso as $llave=>$Producto_compra)


    
    <tr>


  <td class="text-center">{{$cont_compra}}</td>
  <td class="text-center">{{$Producto_compra['id_producto_compra']}} 
  </td>

    <td class="text-center"> 
   {{$Producto_compra['codigo_producto_compra']}}</td>
        
  
      <td class="text-center"> 
     {{$Producto_compra['nombre_producto_compra']}}</td> 
        
      <td class="text-center">{{$Producto_compra['talla_compra']}}</td>
      
      <td class="text-center">{{$Producto_compra['talla_ropa_compra']}} 
      </td>
      <td class="text-center"> 
     {{$Producto_compra['cantidad_disponible_compra']}}</td>
      <td> 
        
      <input type="text" id="cantidad_{{$cont_compra}}" 
  name="cantidad_[]"  class="inputcantidad form-control" 
  onchange="calculate(),validatecantidad(this)" placeholder="cantidad" 
  required="" ></td> 
     
      <td> 

      <input type="text" id="precio_{{$cont_compra}}"  name ="precio_[]" 
  class="input-precio form-control" 
 onchange="calculate(),validateprecio(this)" placeholder="precio de 
 compra unitario" required="" ></td> 
        
      <td class="text-center"> <label class="subtotal"  for="">0</label>
      </td>
      
      <td>
```

```
       </td>
    </tr>
    @php($cont_compra++)
    @endforeach
    @endforeach
    @endif
    
</tbody>
</table> 
<div class="float-right">
  <input type="text" class="float-right" id="resultado_total" value="0" 
 disabled >Total: </input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podés utilizar la funcion array_push() que es nativa de php, te doy el mismo ejemplo que esta en la documentación oficial y te va a servir para entender como aplicarla;

```
<?php
     $stack = array("orange", "banana");
     array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry");
     print_r($stack);
?>
```

Esto daría como salida;

```
Array
(
    [0] => orange
    [1] => banana
    [2] => apple
    [3] => raspberry
)
```

Comment: Hola, pero quedo en las mismas, me añade siempre un nuevo array

Comment: Te molestaría mostrar todo el controlador, entiendo que subiste explicando paso a paso lo que querías hacer, pero aun no me queda claro y quiero ayudar, ¿podrias mostrarlo todo?

Comment: O al menos mostrame como implementaste array_push() poque esa funcion no va a cargar los datos siempre en la misma posicion.

Comment: Hola, creo que yo me equivoque en formular la pregunta  lo que necesito es que ese elemento pase como coleccion a mi variable sesion    que quede  mas o menos asi  0->elemento pera  1->elemento manzana    3->elemento durazno al dar click al boton

Comment: Bueno, pero tengamos en cuenta lo siguiente, vos querés trabajar con Colecciones, o con Arrays, recordemos que son cosas distintas, si es para agregar un elemento nuevo en un array, tenes los helpers de Laravel, por ejemplo Arr::add(), que podes verlo en su documentacion oficial https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-add

Comment: Lo mismo, si necesitas trabajar con Colecciones, que para mi es la mejor opcion, tambien tenes toda la documentacion en https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections

Comment: $array = collect($producto_array);


$nuevo=$array->prepend($producto_array);    ago un dd (pero no me muestra la siguiente posision)

Comment: Trying to access array offset on value of type int en el blade al intentar itentar iterar la coleccion